# Virtualenv installed package not found

Tags: python, django

I installed a django-secure into a virtualenv using pip.  The install was normal.  The module shows up in the virtualenv pip list and in virtualenvs/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages.  I get the following error when running my code.

ImportError: No module named djangosecure

The folder is in there and there is an **init**. No install issues.  What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you running your code in a virtual environment?

Comment: I just figured out that my wsgi file was pointed to the wrong virtualenv. Sometiems it the simple things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your wsgi file points to the right virtualenv!